# How to fix gulp connect in gulp v4

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have painfully realized the gulp has switched to V4 and now all my projects tasks are broken. I have managed to fix most of the issues but gulp-connect seems to be not working properly.

```js
// Include Gulp
var gulp = require('gulp');

// Include required plugins.
var connect = require('gulp-connect');

// TASK: connect
gulp.task('connect', function() {
    connect.server({
        livereload: true,
    });
});

// TASK: preview
gulp.task('preview', function () {
    gulp.src('index.html')
        .pipe(connect.reload());
});

// TASK: watch
gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('*.html', gulp.parallel('preview'));
});

// Task Bundles
gulp.task('default',
    gulp.parallel('connect', 'watch'));
```

I am editing my index.html file but nothing is refreshing in the browser. How to fix this issue?